# Declaring Constant and assigning character in C#

Tags: c#

How do i declare something like this in c# ?

I am trying to cut ticket through opos printer but this is not working out.

Here is the code in c#:

```
Public Const eCut As String = Chr(27) + "i" + vbCrLf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for a code converter? What you've posted is in vb. Here's the code in c#:

```
public const string eCut = Strings.Chr(27) + "i" + System.Environment.NewLine
```

and here's a good vb to c# (and vice versa) converter for future reference: http://converter.telerik.com/